# DateTime.Parse fails when hyphen is used as the separator in the time format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.5

Prerequisites:
In the Windows regional settings choose *English (United States)* formats. In the *Additional settings* customize time format by specifying hyphen as the separator (like "HH-mm-ss").

After these changes, the following code fails with FormatException (*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*):

```
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Reproduced in .NET 4.0 and 4.5.
Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: `HH-mm-ss` isn't a DateTime. Date. Time.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString() returns something like a "10/12/2013 15-30-32". "10/12/2013 15-30-32" contains both date and time. Moreover, it is completely legal to parse date-only or time-only strings.
I.e. DateTime.Parse("10/12/2013") gets {10/12/2013 12-00-00 AM}.
DateTime.Parse("3:45:30 PM") gets {10/12/2013 3-45-30 PM}

Comment: Using a hyphen is a very awkward choice, it also matches the negative number symbol.  DateTime.Parse() can no longer distinguish the separator from an (incorrect) negative value for minutes or seconds.  This squarely fits my doctor's usual advice: if it hurts then don't do it.

Comment: I think that any coerced format is a very awkward choice. Therefore I wanna use the format specified in Windows regional settings. Moreover, the user may use different formats allowed for their culture (like HH:mm and HH:mm:ss), therefore I cannot just use `DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("G"), "G", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact method.
For example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(),"HH-mm-ss",null);
```

Comment: Is there some sort of DateTime.ParseUsingCustomSettings() method? Whilst an interesting solution, it seems fragile as stands.

Comment: You can use TryParseExact method with an array of string formats, and the return value is a Boolean that indicates if the parse had succeeded. Here is a documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx

Comment: So what do you need? Parse it depends on the culture?
You can do that, check the overloads here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx
You can also do that in the regular Parse method.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe this is obvious, but instead of:

```
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

Just do this:

```
DateTime.Now
```

String formats can be used for many things, but not all formats are guaranteed to fully round-trip when converted to a string and parsed back to a `DateTime` again.  You may have noticed specifically because the time separator was mucked with, but it's also because you're using the default string format.  If you had instead used this, it would have worked, even with the strange regional settings:

```
DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("o"))
```

But still, there's almost never a good reason to do that in the real world.

You may want to read about the [Standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format strings for `DateTime`.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString())` is a simplified example.
Consider an application which provides the user with an ability to enter date and time.
When the application is started, it converts the stored DateTime value to a text and loads it to a text box, then the user can modify the value and the application should convert it back to a DateTime.
In this scenario, the user will is unable to modify entered date and time when hyphen is used as a separator.
Moreover, I've reproduced this issue with TimePicker from the WPFToolkit ([link](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)).

Comment: If hyphen is both the date and the time separator, how do you expect `DateTime.Parse("1-2-3")` to distinguish between Jan 2 0003 (date) and 01:02:03 (time)?  I think your expectations are unreasonable.